# button click event not working after append data from php

Tags: php, jquery, html, events, click

I am loading html with javascript from php to a div using $.get() to a div. the button click event is working fine. then adding again same thing again to different div with different id, but it is not working. can anyone can help me. my code is this

```
<style>
    .loadWindow {
        width:333px;
        height: 202px;
        padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
        font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        border:double;
    }

    #loadWindow {
        display:none;
    }
```

```
<div id="main-box">
<div class="loadWindow" id="loadWindow"></div><button id="make">make</button>
```

My javascript code is below

```
$(function(){
    $('#make').click(function(){
        var id = $('.loadWindow').length;
        var aw = $('#loadWindow').clone().attr("id", "window"+id);

        //load data from php
        $.get("mydata.php", function(data) {
            aw.html(data);  
            $('#main-box').append(aw);
            aw.show();
        }, 'json');
    });
});
```

`

My mydata.php code is below

```
echo '<div><button id="closeBtn">Close</button></div><script>$("#closeBtn").click(function(){alert("Close button Clicked!");});</script>';
```

I want click event work for each window separately(individually) and display the alert. In this code click event is not working according to the window. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/QYEWs/13/

Please use `.on` API to it attaches an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

API: http://api.jquery.com/on/

**Plz Note:** your append will make the DOM invalid as your id will always be same make it a class

to attach click event on dynamically added html in DOM

This should help, `:)`

like this

Attaché click event to close button like this:

```
$("#main-box").on("click",".closeBtn", function() {
    alert("Close button Clicked!");
});​


$(function(){
    $('#make').on('click', function(){
        var id = $('.loadWindow').length;
        var aw = $('#loadWindow').clone().attr("id", "window"+id);

        //load data from php
        $.get("mydata.php", function(data) {
            aw.html(data);  
            $('#main-box').append(aw);
            aw.show();
        }, 'json');
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but I am loading html dynamically and there will be more buttons and using buttons for different actions. The main thing is how to know which div i am appending the data, then only i can make the code with '.on' in my click events. I checked the code creates different id for different load windows (i mean window1, window2, etc). So I am loading html with scripts that tells what to do when click on specified button. I am making something like class which has its own functions, inputs, buttons and appearances. do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('#make').click(function(){
        var id = $('.loadWindow').length;
        var aw = $('#loadWindow').clone(true).attr("id", "window"+id);
        //load data from php
        $.get("mydata.php", function(data) {
            aw.html(data);  
            $('#main-box').append(aw);
            aw.show();
        }, 'json');
    });
});
```